# WPF: Apply ScrollBar Style to ListBox Template - Error object cannot be added to border

Tags: wpf, listbox, styles

I thought this may be straightforward question but did not find any definitive answer while searching net or SO.

I have created a `ScrollBar` style (using standard scroll bard template - Blend 2)

I am not sure how to apply this style "MyScrollStyle" to a `ListBox` Template .

I saw on `ListBox` template they have a `ScrollViewer` --> which should contain the `ScrollBar`.

Assuming it is something simple as:

```
<Setter Property ="Template" value="{Static Resource  MyScrollStyle}"/>
```

---Content Added---

After going through lot of xaml in template edit I kind of understood how to apply style. I am trying to add the  scroll view style set in this example -http://blog.xamltemplates.net/wp-content/uploads/2008/12/scrollviewer.zip, to my list view template but it gives the following error:

```
System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException was unhandled
  Message="'ScrollViewer' object cannot be added to 'Border'. Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.  Error at object 'System.Windows.Controls.ScrollViewer' in markup file 'MenuModule, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null;component/resources/Resources.xaml' Line 19 Position 26."
  Source="PresentationFramework"
  LineNumber=19
  LinePosition=26
  NameContext="1_T"
```

Any help is appreciated

Thank you,
The Mar

Comment: from Template:
       <ScrollViewer Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Focusable="false">
        <ItemsPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
       </ScrollViewer>

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong: I have to edit template for ScrollViewer and use ScrollBar Style in scroll Viewer. I should apply ScrollViewer style to ListBox

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify the `ListBox.Template`, find `ScrollViewer` inside and apply the style, or disable scroll on `ListBox` and put it in `ScrollViewer` with your style.

Comment: Thank you Gimlay. If I put Listbox inside  scrolviewer will I be able to do UI Virtualization for the LisBoxItems

Comment: No, it will not work. But in most cases this is not necessary. If you need virtualization edit ListBox Template.